# Is there a way to show/enable mnemonic description in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

I am currently working on java byte code in GHIDRA and I was just wondering if there was a way to show the instruction descriptions like there is in IDA and x64dbg.

For e.g

bipush - Push byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing Ghidra has (to my knowledge) to what you want is the "Processor Manual" feature. You can download the [JVM spec for version 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf) and place it in `\ghidra_XX.X.X_PUBLIC\Ghidra\Processors\JVM\data\manuals`. The JVM.idx file describes where in the processor manual to look for the specific instruction you're asking about. If you right-clicked on a `bipush` instruction and clicked "Processor manual" it would then pull up your jvms8.pdf file and flip to page 396 where it talks about the `bipush` instruction.

I'm not sure if you can add it to the end of the line. The per-instruction view in Ghidra can be customized when you click on the button at the top of the Listing window (it should say "Edit the Listing fields") - that will allow you, for instance, to rearrange the order the address/instruction/bytes appear. By editing the listing, you for instance can turn on the Pcode viewer that lets you see the intermediate language.

If you were going to turn on instruction descriptions, that is the place you would do it. However, I don't see an option to do it.

Comment: Thank you dingo